# Symfony form not honoring set defaults

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a pretty simple form with some fields from a doctrine model.

```
$this->widgetSchema['fields'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(
  'model'          => 'FieldModel',
  'expanded'       => true,
  'multiple'       => true,));

$this->validatorSchema['fields'] = new sfValidatorDoctrineChoice(array(
  'model'    => 'FieldModel',
  'multiple' => true,));
```

The fields are rendered in the form as checkboxes and I'm able to check and save correctly. This 'fields'-field is converted to a json-structure and saved to the database as text. So far so good.

NOTE: The field 'fields' is stored as TEXT in the database, but the user should be able to select values from a list of checkboxes.

The problem arise when I want to have some of the checkboxes checked by default.

I tried to do:

```
$this->setDefault('fields', array('key1','key2','key3'));
```

Where 'keyX' correspond to the actual value of the primary key (string) for Field in the database.

If I do a

```
$this->getDefault('fields');
```

I get back exactly what I put in previously.

However, symfony is not outputing any of the checkboxes as checked. I have even tried to remove both the 'expanded' and 'multiple' options to the choice-widget so I get a simple SELECT-box and the provide only one value as default selected.

Setting default values for other widgets (text-inputs, choice, etc) work.

Btw; The Field-model is i18n. Don't know if that matters here, since both storing / retrieving works as expected.

Also; the form is rendered as part of another form by means of include_partial(). Can that sabotage anything? In the 'parent' form class:

```
$this->embedRelation('TheRelationThatBugsMe');
```

And then in the _form.php for the 'parent':

```
include_partial('the_relation_that_bugs_me/form', array('form' => $form['TheRelationThatBugsMe']));
```

Does anyone have an idea where I might have gone wrong, or at least can give me some pointers as to where I should start digging?

**[UPDATE]**

If I create a new field in the form 'fields2' (that does not exist as a field in the database) and use *the exact same* code to create widget, validator and set defaults, then the defaults are rendered correctly. How come it doesn't work setting defaults for a field mapped to a column in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're calling `setDefault` before `updateDefaultFromObject` gets called in `sfDoctrineForm`, then the object's values will override form defaults if the object exists. `updateDefaultsFromObject` contains the relevant logic. You'll have to call `setDefault` later, or override the method.